# MATLAB list manipulation

Tags: matlab, matrix

Consider I have a code segment as follows:

**Case 1**

```
n = 20;
for i = 2 : n
    mat = rand([2,i]);
    mat = [mat, mat(:,1)]; %add the first column to the last
    %feed the variable 'mat' to a function 
end
```

**Case 2**

```
n = 10;
list = [];
for i = 1 : n
    a = rand([2,1]);
    b = rand([2,2])
    list = [list, [a,b]];
end
```

In this way, MATLAB gives the below suggestion:

> The variable 'mat' appears to change size on every loop. Consider preallocating for speed up.
>
> The variable 'list' appears to change size on every loop. Consider preallocating for speed up.

I am a MATLAB newconer, So I would like to know how to deal with this issue. How to do this **in native MATLAB style**? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? There are essential parts that are missing, especially the loop. Also, what do you mean by: _"add the first column to the last"_? Do you want to add the, as in `plus`, or replace the last column, or add it as a separate column, expanding the matrix (this is what you do now)?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks for your suggestion. Indeed I forgot the loop.

Comment: This snippet makes no sense. You create a new matrix in each iteration step, then you append a column, then in the next iteration step you overwrite again. This is equivalent to: `mat = rand([2,20]); mat = [mat, mat(:,1)];` so as actually no loop is needed you can forget about the warning... Or you could specify what do you want to perform.

Comment: Does the code you have work as intended? I.e. is it just the warning that bothers you? Also, I quote: _"This snippet makes no sense"_...

Comment: Regarding your question... google-ing MATLAB + preallocation leads you here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html

Comment: @DVarga The cse 1 and case 2 came from my [fact code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3iUB.png)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Sorry for my simple question. that just a warning and it didn't bother me.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll focus on the second case, as it's the only one that makes sense:

```
n = 10;
list = [];
for i = 1 : n
    a = rand([2,1]);
    b = rand([2,2])
    list = [list, [a,b]];
end
```

That you are doing here, for each loop, is to create two vectors with random numbers, `a` and `b`. `a` has dimension `2x1`, and `b` has dimension `2x2`. Then, you concatenate these two, with the matrix `list`.

Note that each call to `rand` are independent, so `rand(2,3)` will behave the same way `[rand(2,2), rand(2,1)]` does.

Now, since you loop 10 times, and you add `rand(2,3)` every time, you're essentially doing `[rand(2,2), rand(2,1), rand(2,2), rand(2,1) ...]`. This is equivalent to `rand(2,30)`, which is a lot faster. Therefore, *"Consider preallocating for speed up."*

---

Now, if your concatenations doesn't contain random matrices, but are really the output from some function that can't output the entire matrix you want, then preallocate and insert it to the matrix using indices:

Let's define a few functions:

```
function x = loopfun(n)
x = n*[1; 2];
end


function list = myfun1(n)
list = zeros(2, n);
for ii = 1:n
    list(:,ii) = loopfun(ii);
end
end

function list = myfun2(n)    
list = [];
for ii = 1:n
    list = [list, loopfun(ii)];
end
end

f1 = @() myfun1(100000); f2 = @() myfun2(100000);
fprintf('Preallocated: %f\nNot preallocated: %f\n', timeit(f1), timeit(f2))

Preallocated: 0.141617
Not preallocated: 0.318272
```

As you can see, the function with preallocation is twice as fast as the function with an increasing sized matrix. The difference is smaller if there are few iterations, but the general idea is the same.

```
f1 = @() myfun1(5); f2 = @() myfun2(5);
fprintf('Preallocated: %f\nNot preallocated: %f\n', timeit(f1), timeit(f2))

Preallocated: 0.000010
Not preallocated: 0.000018
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use `rand` for simply my question. In fact, the `a `and `b` come from return values of other fucntion. According to my implementation, `a` is a matrix of `2 x i`, and `b` is a matrix of `2 x j`, where `i` and `j` range from 1 to 5.